# Is it possible for R to ignore a line in a user-created function if there is an error?

Tags: r

I am learning R through the Hands on Programming with R book and created a function called roll2 to simulate rolling a pair of user-entered dice. Below is the creation of the function and me attempting to call it.

```
roll2 <- function(bones) {
+ dice <- sample(bones, size = 2, replace = TRUE) +
+ sum(dice) }
> roll2(1:20)
> roll2(1:20)
> x <- roll2(1:20)
> x
[1] 19 21
```

Can someone help me identify why it is returning the variable dice and not the sum(dice) here?

I later rewrote the function and am not having the same problem, output below:

```
> roll2 <- function(bones) {
+ dice <- sample(bones, size = 2, replace = TRUE)
+ sum(dice) }
> roll2(bones = 1:8)
[1] 8
> roll2(bones = 1:8)
[1] 9
> roll2(bones = 1:8)
[1] 5
> roll2(bones = 1:8)
[1] 9
> roll2(bones = 1:8)
[1] 5
> roll2(1:20)
[1] 28
```

I thought it was because I did not explicitly write out the bones argument, but in the final line of the second code block it worked somehow.

Any insight would be great!

I am learning R through the Hands on Programming with R book and created a function called roll2 to simulate rolling a pair of user-entered dice. I was expecting to obtain the summation of the two dice and instead got the sample results from my function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Maybe there was something in your R session that went away when you rewrote the function.

Comment: Okay, thank you for looking into it, if it happens again is it best to reload RStudio?

Comment: is there an extra `+` at the end of the first line of the function body in your first example ... ?

Comment: If the error is unexplainable and sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't, then yes, close everything and rerun RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Your question line is ambiguous and doesn't seem to relate to your problem.  Let me answer two versions for future readers.

1. Can the R "engine" simply ignore a code line?  No, although you can suppress the error message itself.
2. Can you write code that will bypass an error without crashing? Yes, see `trycatch` .

As an aside, I recommend against using `+` in that way.  Write each statement on its own line.  That will reduce the chance that a different text editor may foul up whitespace in some way that gets `+` misinterpreted as the `add` function.